# How to run a regression row by row

Tags: r, loops, row, regression

I just started using R for statistical purposes and I appreciate any kind of help.

As a first step, I ran a time series regression over my columns. Y values are dependent and the X is explanatory.

```
# example
Y1 <- runif(100, 5.0, 17.5)
Y2 <- runif(100, 4.0, 27.5)
Y3 <- runif(100, 3.0, 14.5)
Y4 <- runif(100, 2.0, 12.5)
Y5 <- runif(100, 5.0, 17.5)
X <- runif(100, 5.0, 7.5)
df1 <- data.frame(X, Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5)

# calculating log returns to provide data for the first regression
n <- nrow(df1)
X_logret <- log(X[2:n])-log(X[1:(n-1)])
Y1_logret <- log(Y1[2:n])-log(Y1[1:(n-1)])
Y2_logret <- log(Y2[2:n])-log(Y2[1:(n-1)])
Y3_logret <- log(Y3[2:n])-log(Y3[1:(n-1)])
Y4_logret <- log(Y4[2:n])-log(Y4[1:(n-1)])
Y5_logret <- log(Y5[2:n])-log(Y5[1:(n-1)])

# bringing the calculated log returns together in one data frame
df2 <- data.frame(X_logret, Y1_logret, Y2_logret, Y3_logret, Y4_logret, Y5_logret)

# running the time series regression
Regression <- lm(as.matrix(df2[c('Y1_logret', 'Y2_logret', 'Y3_logret', 'Y4_logret', 'Y5_logret')]) ~ df2$X)

# extracting the coefficients for further calculation
Regression$coefficients[2,(1:5)]
```

As a second step I want to run a regression row by row, which is day by day, since the data contains daily observed values. I also have a column "DATE" but I didn't know how to bring it in here in the example. The format of the DATE column is POSIXct, maybe someone has an idea how to refer to a certain period in it on which the regression should be done.
In the row by row regression I would like to use the 5 calculated coefficients (from the first regression) as an explanatory variable. The 5 Y_logret values, I would like to use as dependent variable.

Y_logret(1 to 5) = Beta * Regression$coefficients[2,(1:5)] + error value. The intercept is not needed, so I would set it to zero by adding +0 in the lm function.

My goal is to run this regression over a period of time, for example over 20 days. Day by day, this would provide a total of 20 Beta estimates (for one regression per day), but I would also need all errors for further calculation. So I have to extract 5 errors per day, that is a total of 20*5 error values.

This is just an example, in the original dataset I have 20 of the Y values and over 4000 rows. I would like to run the regression over certain intervals with 900-1000 day. Since I am completely new to R, I have no idea how to proceed. Especially how to code this in a few lines.

I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: I need the time interval to say: I want to do the row by row regression (cross sectional regression) beginning from the date of 2007-01-01 to 2007-01-20. That would make 20 days and that means 20 regressions.

Comment: Oh, OK. So 20 regressions are there are like 99 rows here so about 5 rows per day? Is that right? There is something else I am confused on. The coefficients, Regression$coefficients[2,(1:5)], those don't change. So if there are constant how could you use them as explanatory variables? There has to be variation between the rows or you can't do it.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Y stands for a stock and X for the index (which contains the stocks) For the first regression I needed X. The row by row regression is only based on the stocks. Per regression one Beta estimate and one error per Y, so 5 errors.

Comment: It is fine if the coefficients from the first Regression don't change. Those 5 should stay constant. Only the log returns in a row do change by period. I only need the Betas from this row by row Regression and the errors.

Comment: This isn't making much sense to me. If they don't change then they can not be used as described in the equation in your question. Can you tell me where this approach comes from? It would be good if we can see the journal article or textbook where this approach is coming from to make it more clear.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266078/loop-through-data-with-sequential-time-lags-output-linear-regression-coefficient/46269638#46269638

Comment: @Hack-R The idea is to calculate risk premiums on stocks. See: [http://jstor.org/stable/1831028] 
The model should work, since we got it from university with these instructions. I just struggle to create an appropriate loop to run the row by row regression.

Comment: I still did not manage to solve this issue, maybe someone has an idea how to proceed. Would be so great.